# Iframe doesn't appear on Mailchimp newsletter campaign

Tags: mailchimp

I am looking for some help with my Mailchimp newsletter campaign so that codes like:

```
<iframe src="http://www.bridgebase.com/tools/handviewer.html?k=s&s=sk32hqj865dcqt542&d=e&v=b&a=1s?" height="300px" width="200px"></iframe>
```

or a poll from ch as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/7690662.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/7690662/">Wat bid je?</a></noscript>
```

Will actually show in the newsletter. I only get to see them in the preview page but once the campaign is sent the info disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could well just be the particular mail client you are using to view the newsletter.

As you can see from this post by Campaign Monitor, including iframes in email newsletters is not a very good idea;

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I've got the same problem with MailChimp template, but I fix the best I can.

The problem is that iframe is not supported, like all the scripts. Under their support section, in the Email Design Reference you can find the reason: *"Don’t bother with JavaScript or Flash—those technologies are largely unsupported by email clients. Avoid elements that require Flash or JavaScript."*

Also [here](https://longreply.com/r/ec2cc6ca) you can find some tips to remedy this problem, suggested by MailChimp:

- a .jpg or .png image of the map and then link to the Google Maps site
- a STATIC MAP powered by Maps API

I tried with the last one and this is the result:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Rome,Italy&zoom=14&size=400x400
```

You can find [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) the documentation for the syntax and all the allowed parameters.